# -lpthread and -pthread option when compiling the pthread code

Tags: pthreads

I've tried to compile the simple pthreading code using g++.

To the best of my knowledge, I should use the `-lpthread` but it cannot make the executable.

Below is the error code (it seems that libpthread doesn't linked):

```
undefined reference to `pthread_create'
```

However, interestingly, when I compile with the option `-pthread` it is correctly compiled and completely working well.

My g++ version is  gcc version 5.2.1 20151010 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2).

Answer (score 1):

the `-l` option indicates the compiler to link the program with the named library, so `-lpthread` means to link the pthread library.
`-pthread` is an option that's required to build
threaded programs in gcc.
`-pthread` is preferred if available.

Comment: I understand what would you like to point out, but interestingly my gcc/ g++ cannot compile the source code with -lpthread option, but it works with -pthread option. Do you know why?
Also when I use two options together it works..

Comment: I just added this flags in Makefile 
CPPFLAGS = -g -pthread -lpthread -std=c++11 -O0

Comment: In general, libraries should follow sources and objects on command. Use `-lpthread` as the last compiler flag.

Comment: Maybe it's the preprocessor error as `-lpthread` doesn't set flags for the preprocessor. You can try with `-lpthread -D_REENTRANT`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134794/discussion-between-jfly-and-jaehyuk-lee).